# Can I track who is linking or manipulating my site's data?

Tags: web-scraping

Is it possible to track if someone links to data on my site?  Specifically if my data is used in a site dynamically generated by a developer program?  I would like to know if someone is blatantly passing off my site's data as their own.  There are obviously ways around directly linking to content, such as content manipulation or even manual manipulation.  But if someone where to link(or directly add word for word or manipulate) my content into their website, is there a way to track it?

Can I avoid someone being able to scrape my website at all, or is everything just up for grabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best answer and the easy one is called GOOGLE - WEBMASTER TOOLS!
[HERE](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=sitemaps&passive=1209600&continue=https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/&followup=https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/)
actually doing that is very hard and you would need to crawl the web to discover those links that address to your pages... dynamic content as well is linked so it would be find by google as well.

this tool will allow you to see outer links that address to your site.. and you can check them.

for extra - you can monitor requests and traffic to your site and find ip's that are using the same page over and over again. that can tell u that an outer page is dynamically loading content from your web page.

**EDIT:**

here is a good article in this subject: [link](http://blog.kissmetrics.com/content-scrapers/) - scroll down and you can see the use of google 
webmaster tool with some other progrmas and method.

here is a good start guide to the google webmaster: [link](http://blog.kissmetrics.com/google-webmaster-tools-2012/)

ENJOY!

Comment: Perfect.  Am i able to see if the same exact content is used even if they dont use a link to my site/content?  I will do some research on my own, just wondering if you know off hand.  Thanks